# XNA Line to Rectangle Collision return first pixel

Tags: xna, collision-detection, linear-algebra

I have the following code:

```
    public static bool LineIntersectsRect(Point p1, Point p2, Rectangle r)
    {
        return LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y), new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X + r.Width, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height)) ||
               LineIntersectsLine(p1, p2, new Point(r.X, r.Y + r.Height), new Point(r.X, r.Y)) ||
               (r.Contains(p1) && r.Contains(p2));
    }

    private static bool LineIntersectsLine(Point l1p1, Point l1p2, Point l2p1, Point l2p2)
    {
        float q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y);
        float d = (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) * (l2p2.Y - l2p1.Y) - (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y) * (l2p2.X - l2p1.X);

        if (d == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        float r = q / d;

        q = (l1p1.Y - l2p1.Y) * (l1p2.X - l1p1.X) - (l1p1.X - l2p1.X) * (l1p2.Y - l1p1.Y);
        float s = q / d;

        if (r < 0 || r > 1 || s < 0 || s > 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

This code checks to see if a line intersects a given rectangle. But I need to find a way to get the position of the first pixel colliding between Point 'p1' and Point 'p2'.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to find the intersection point in your LineIntersectsLine method.

Add something like this last:

```
Vector2 t0 = l1p2 - l1p1;
Vector2 t1 = l2p2 - l2p1;
Vector2 t2 = l2p1 - l1p1;

float dotDPerp = t0.X * t1.Y - t0.Y * d.X;
float t = (t2.X * t1.Y - t2.Y * t1.X) / dotDPerp;

Vector2 intersection = l1p1 + t * t0;
```